# Returning from a catch block groovy

Tags: groovy

I'm confused as to why this method always returns even when an exception is caught... shouldn't it return after logging the error?

```
private def sendConfCode(sendTo)
    {

        def confCode = genConfCode()
        try
        {
            mail.sendMessage(sendTo.toString(), "Your confirmation code is", confCode)
            //insert confCode into temporary banner table?
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            logIt.writeLog(e.message, Priority.ERR)
        }
        return confCode + " - " + sendTo
    }
```

Comment: how do you know that an exception is thrown? apply system out and see if the exception is caught, if it is then it is an error with your logger

Comment: Why *wouldn't* it return after an exception is caught? Or do you mean that it's specifically *not* writing the message (and flushing it etc.)

Comment: I know I'm getting an exception. I want execution to stop in the catch block. I feel stupid ... restructured the method and got it to do what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct code:

```
private def sendConfCode(sendTo)
    {

        def confCode = genConfCode()
        def sent=false
        try
        {

            mail.sendMessage(sendTo.toString(), "Your confirmation code is", confCode)
            //insert confCode into temporary banner table?
            sent = true
        }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        logIt.writeLog(e.message, Priority.ERR)
    }
    return sent

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should return after logging the error, this is probably the error in your logger configuration if indeed the exception is thrown.

If you want execution to stop in the catch block then return from there

```
private def sendConfCode(sendTo)
    {

        def confCode = genConfCode()
        try
        {
            mail.sendMessage(sendTo.toString(), "Your confirmation code is", confCode)
            //insert confCode into temporary banner table?
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            logIt.writeLog(e.message, Priority.ERR)
            return
        }
        return confCode + " - " + sendTo
}
```